# Anaconda wont install in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to install Anaconda on my laptop running the latest version of elementary os. I followed the steps on the official site. http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/ However when I reached the end of the process and restarted my terminal the following lines came up:

```
bash: /home/anton/.bashrc: line 171: syntax error near unexpected token `added'

bash: /home/anton/.bashrc: line 171: esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer'
```

When i typed anaconda-navigator hoping it would open, I got a error:

```
anaconda-navigator: command not found
```

I'm very new to Linux and your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the line 171 and as follows:

```
esac# added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer'
```

should be

```
esac #added by Anaconda3 5.3.0 installer'
```